# VBA script: Code Runs fine in Debug mode but not in full run mode

Tags: excel, vba

VBA script: Code Runs fine in Debug mode but not in full run mode.
Code is to read each cell in Col I, check for 1st pos IF numeric and then write the Pos of the same in Col J ?

The code runs fine in debug mode but not in full run.

CODE writteN

```
Dim CellRef As String
Dim StringLength As Integer
j = 1
i = 1

For j = 2 To LastRow1
   StringLength = Len(Cells(j, "I"))
   i = 1
   For i = 1 To StringLength
      If IsNumeric(Mid((Cells(j, "I")), i, 1)) Then
         Cells(j, "J") = i
         i = StringLength + 1
      End If
   Next i
Next j
```

Comment: what issue are you seeing when running in "full run"?

Comment: Fully qualify your cells object.. for example `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "I")` etc...

Comment: Could it be that you run the macro from a different worksheet than while debugging? You should full qualify your ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have variables declared before or not. To avoid the that come by not declaring them, I recommend you using `Option Explicit`at the top of your code.

On the other hand, I guess your problem comes from the `ActiveSheet` at the moment you are running your macro, since you didn't full qualify your ranges, they go to the `ActiveSheet` to avoid this you can read the comments:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TesT()

    Dim CellRef As String 'not sure if you are using it later
    Dim StringLength As Long ' you used Integer, Byte or Long, Integer is a Long cutted.
    Dim MyRange As Range 'we will set here the working range
    Dim C As Range 'It is always better to loop through cells with For Each
    Dim LastRow1 As Long 'Not sure if you declared it before
    Dim i As Long 'Not sure if you declared it before

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SeetName") 'always full qualify your ranges: workbook-worksheet-range
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column I
        Set MyRange = .Range("I2:I" & LastRow1) 'this will be your working range
        For Each C In MyRange 'this will loop through all the cells between J2 to J LastRow1
            StringLength = Len(C)
            For i = 1 To StringLength
                If IsNumeric(Mid((C), i, 1)) Then
                   .Cells(j, "J") = i 'full qualify the range, note the "." before Cells, referencing to the with line
                   Exit For 'this will exit the loop so only the first match remains.
                   ' i = StringLength + 1 'don't know why did you do this, but if you intend to keep the first position the above line is it.
                End If
            Next i
        Next C
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Below is the Code I added. But am getting "Application or Object defined error". The ask is to copy the first position of a "numeric pos" appearing in the value in Cell I to be copied in Cell J. So if i see ur code I dont see anything copied to Col J. Pardon if i missed explaining this.

Comment: With wkb2.Sheets("FilteredList") 
        'LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 
        Set MyRange = .Range("I2:" & LastRow1) 
        For Each C In MyRange 
            StringLength = Len(C)
            For i = 1 To StringLength
                If IsNumeric(Mid((C), i, 1)) Then
                   wkb2.Sheets("FilteredList").Cells(j, "J").Value = i 
                   Exit For 
                   ' i = StringLength + 1 
                End If
            Next i
        Next C
    End With

Comment: It worked when i used "Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "I") etc..." to my original code